# How can I arrange the materialize css cards in a row while those cards are holding data fetched from mysql database

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, materialize

I am trying to fetch data from database into Materialize CSS cards. What I want is only 3 cards in one row. After 3rd card in one row, it should display next 3 cards in next new row automatically.

[image: Here is the snapshot of how it is getting displayed now.]
[And this is how I want to display it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3b4G.png)
And here is my code for that snapshot.

```
<?php
        $cnt=1;
        $sql=mysqli_query($db,"select * from addevent");
        $row=mysqli_num_rows($sql);

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                echo"<div class='card amber lighten-1' style='grid-auto-flow:row; width:300px;margin-left:10px;'>
                                <div class='card-content'>";
                                    echo "<span class='card-title activator teal-text text-darken-3'>".$row['EventName']."<i class='material-icons right'>more_vert</i></span>";
                                    echo "<h6 class='teal-text text-darken-3'>".$row['Oname']."</h6>";
                                    echo "<h5 class='brown-text text-lighten-3'>".$row['EventDate']." | ".$row['EventTime']."</h5>";
                                    echo "<p class='deep-orange-text text-lighten-1'>".$row['EventAddress']."</p>";
                                echo"</div>";

                                echo"<div class='card-reveal'>";
                                    echo "<span class='card-title orange-text text-lighten-1'>".$row['EventName']."<i class='material-icons right'>close</i></span>";
                                    echo "<p class='teal-text text-lighten-2'>".$row['AboutEvent']."</p>";
                                echo"</div>";
                        echo"</div>";

            }
            echo"</div>";
    ?>
```

Comment: So have you made any attempt to actually do what you want?

Comment: Whatever I have posted is done by me.

Comment: I understand that, but it really makes no attempt to achieve "only 3 cards in one row. After 3rd card in one row, it should display next 3 cards in next new row".  Without seeing anything further, it's not clear what part is causing you problems.

Comment: I have added another snapshot to make it more clear that how exactly I want to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Just let a counter run in every iteration.
Once the counter reaches 3, you simply close the current row and open a new one.
Don't forget to reset the counter to 1 after that.